# android Firedatabase update data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have managed to connect  my android app to a fire database    , the add method works fine , this is my data base i created [image]

lets say i have 3 buttons each one represents a hotel with the hotel name as a text ,lets say i clicked on the button that holds the text aze , i am looking for a way to decrements the number of chambers by 1 where hotel name is aze , how do i do that ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this for updating value in fire base

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("Hotels")
                         .child(model.getUid())
                          .child("chambers") 
                          .setValue(YourValueHere);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: what's a model.getUid()

Comment: Replace it with your node UUID, i.e if you want to update data of 'aze' the node name will come there.

Comment: KieqUXeYm thats the name of node ,just replace it there

Answer (score 0):

Well first i will advice you to read the firebase documentation.If you do not understand then ask.
But still what you have to is type this code in onClick method.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hotels");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>> nameMap = (HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (nameMap != null) {
                for (String key : nameMap.keySet()) {
                   HashMap<String,Object> hotel=nameMap.getValue(key);
                   if(hotel.getValue("adresse").toString().equals("aze"))
                   {
                    Long chambers=(Long)hotel.getValue("chamber");
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("chambers", chambers-1);
                    DatabaseReference childDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hotels").child("key").updateChildren(map);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

I have not tested this so errors might come.
But it is like this only.